# Remove Punctuation At The End Of A String C++

Tags: c++

How do I remove a specific type of punctuation at the end of a string? I want to remove "-" a.k.a. hyphens. I only want to remove them at the end of the string. Thanks.

UPDATE: User Christophe has provided a good solution for those who are using anything less than c++11!
The code is below:

```
for (int n=str.length(); n && str[--n]=='-'; str.resize(n));
```

Comment: In a loop you check if the last symbol is equal to `-` and remove it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
while (str.length() && str.back() == '-') 
    str.pop_back();
```

Comment: what if `str` is empty?

Comment: Yes, I just noticed and added the test on length !

Comment: @landesko I tested this code in all kind of conditions and it works.  If the very last char is '-' (and not if there is a space after the '-').  Attention, back() and pop_back() are both c++11

Comment: Ok !  Then a variant:  `for (int n=str.length(); n && str[--n]=='-'; str.resize(n));`

Comment: Is there a way to say if str.end() == '-' then remove it? I haven't been able to figure out if this is possible in c++.

Comment: Your variant worked! Thank you so much man. I hope you have a wonderful life.

Answer (score 1):

Boost's solution is worth a mention:

```
std::string cat = "meow-";
boost::trim_right_if(cat,boost::is_any_of("-"));
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/773a21394336757d)

Check out the indispensable [boost string algo](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

Using some useful properties of `std::string`, namely `find_last_of()`, `find_last_not_of()`, `substr()`, and `length()`:

```
std::string DeHyphen(const std::string input){
    std::string dehyphened = input;
    if ((dehyphened.length() - 1) == dehyphened.find_last_of("-")) //If we have a hyphen in the last spot,
        return dehyphened.substr(0, dehyphened.find_last_not_of("-")); //Return the string ending in the last non-hyphen character.
    else return dehyphened; //Else return string.
}
```

Note that this will not work for strings consisting only of hyphens- you will just get the string back. If you want instead an empty string in that instance, simply check for that in the case where the 'if' evaluates true.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` has a `find_last_not_of` member function that makes it easy to find the correct position:

```
size_t p = your_string.find_last_not_of('-');
```

From there, it's a simple matter of erasing the content from there to the end of the string:

```
your_string.erase(pos);
```

If the string doesn't have any hyphens at the end, the `find_last_not_of` will return `std::string::npos`. The overload of `erase` we're using here takes parameters for both the beginning and ending positions to erase, but sets the end point to `std::string::npos` as the default. Calling it as `your_string.erase(npos, npos)` leaves the string unchanged, so we don't need any special code for that case. Since the erase doesn't need to be conditional, you can combine the two pretty easily as well:

```
your_string.erase(your_string.find_last_not_of('-'));
```

Comment: With this I'm getting an unhandled exception. It says I'm out of range at a certain memory location.

Comment: @landesko: In that case you're doing something else wrong. As I often do, I've left a defect or two in the code, but (as usual) it/they is/are pretty trivial, and certainly shouldn't lead to anything like an unhandled exception.